# Executing mysql queries sequentially nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await

I am pretty new to nodejs and am using it to construct an api with a mysql database and have run into an issue where I am unable to execute mysql queries sequentially.

The database structure is that there are three tables. Table a in a one to many relation with table b, which is in a one to many relation with table c.

I need a GET endpoint where aid is given and it returns a result with an array of items of b with the array of items of c nested inside it.

Sample Result:

{
logcode: "",
logmessage: "",
bitems: [{
bitemid: 1
citems: [{
citemid: 1
} {
citemid: 2
}]
}{
bitemid: 2
citems: [{
citemid: 3
}]
}]
}

Currently I am attempting to do this by first executing a query where I retrieve all the values of type b that correspond to the received key of entity a and then running a foreach loop over the results and extracting the bitem ids and then running another query within the foreach loop to get all items of table c with that specific foreign key.

```
async function (req, res) {

   let functionname = 'getAllItems'

   const conLocalPool = db.conLocalPool.promise();
   var data = {}
   const atoken = req.get('token');

   var str = ``;

   str = `call ${functionname}('${atoken}')`;
   console.log(str);
   try {
       const [rows, fields] = await conLocalPool.query(str)
       data = rows[0][0]
       if (data.logcode === 20100) {
           data.bitems = rows[1];
           data.bitems.forEach(async (bitem) => {
               var stmt = `Select * from \`table-c\` where bitemid=${bitem.id}`
               try {
                   const [citemrows, citemfields] = await conLocalPool.query(stmt);
                   console.log(citemrows[1])
                   bitem.citems = citemrows[1];
                   return true;
               }
               catch (err) {
                   console.log(err);
                   return false;
               }

           })
       }
       res.status(200).send(data);
       return true;
   }


   catch (err) {
       res.status(500).send({
           error: err.message
       });
       return false;
   }
}
```

Using this function, I am able to get a response which contains all the bitems related to the aitemtoken but without the citems related to each individual bitem.

I would like some help on how to execute the first query and then the later queries based on the response that it retrieves.

Comment: I'm assuming that the later queries will use some field from the first query as condition reference? In `WHERE .. ` maybe?

Comment: Yeah, I need the id from the first query for the later queries.

Comment: The same id that you use in the first query condition?

Comment: No, the first query would have the id received from the request. The later queries would use ids from the rows returned from the first query. Query 1-> Returns 10 items, I would need to run 10 queries, one each for each item with it's id

Comment: Will those 10 queries be running the same query only differentiated by the id? For example "later query 1"=`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id="1"` , "later query 2"=`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id="2"` .. and so on?

Comment: Yep, only the id would change.

Comment: Why don't you just use 1 query and do something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (Select * from \`table-c\` where bitemid=${bitem.id})`? That's one suggestion, it might not be quick but it gets the job done. Similarly you can use `EXISTS` or `JOIN` etc..

Comment: Ah, ok. Do you mean to get the rows using joins and to restructure the data in the response on the node of things?

Comment: I guess so.. by the way, where will you show the end result? a webpage?

Comment: I'll be sending a json back in the format Ive mentioned here and then yeah, display it on a webpage.

Comment: Actually, I think maybe I wasn't clear...I'll try an example lol. Ive got a table of users. A table of dogs(each user can have multiple dogs) and a table of dog toys(each dog can have multiple toys). I am looking for a way to simply send a single userid and return all the dogs he/she owns and each of the toys owned by each dog and then return it as {id:1dogs:[dogid: 1,toys:[]]} I am not entirely sure if my method is the right way to do it but I dont understand specifically how to use exists or join to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your last comment, I'm sure that you can achieve it by doing `JOIN`. There are a few ways to do it but consider this example below:

```
SELECT * FROM owner o 
JOIN dogs d ON o.id=d.owner_id
JOIN dog_toys t ON d.id=t.dog_id
WHERE o.id=1;
```

Assuming that you have 3 tables (owner, dogs & dog_toys) and each of the table have a relation of `owner.id=dogs.owner_id` and `dogs.id=dog_toys.dog_id`, you can simply `JOIN` all three of them in one query and modify the returned results in `SELECT`.

I've created a sample fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ukBgL4M3NzkyTDC6nMGkJn/1

Comment: Thanks for your help :D I get it now.